# How to enable overwriting output files in scrapy settings.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, scrapy-splash

As can be found in the [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#feeds), it states:

> New in version 2.4.0.
>
> overwrite: whether to overwrite the file if it already exists (True)
> or append to its content (False).

I inserted in the `settings.py` - file of my `scrapy`-project the following:

```
FEEDS = {"overwrite": True}
```

This led to the following error-output upon executing `scrapy crawl quotes_splash -o Outputs/quotes_splash.json`:

```
(scrapy_course) andylu@andylu-Lubuntu-PC:~$ scrapy crawl quotes_splash -o Outputs/quotes_splash.json
2020-12-02 18:11:59 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.4.1 started (bot: quotes_spider_splash)
2020-12-02 18:11:59 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.6.1.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.9.0 (default, Nov 22 2020, 23:12:14) - [GCC 5.5.0], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1h  22 Sep 2020), cryptography 3.2.1, Platform Linux-5.4.0-56-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.31
2020-12-02 18:11:59 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor
2020-12-02 18:11:59 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'quotes_spider_splash',
 'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter',
 'HTTPCACHE_STORAGE': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'quotes_spider_splash.spiders',
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['quotes_spider_splash.spiders']}
2020-12-02 18:11:59 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andylu/.virtualenvs/scrapy_course/bin/scrapy", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/home/andylu/.virtualenvs/scrapy_course/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 145, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/home/andylu/.virtualenvs/scrapy_course/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 100, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/andylu/.virtualenvs/scrapy_course/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 153, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/home/andylu/.virtualenvs/scrapy_course/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 22, in run
    crawl_defer = self.crawler_process.crawl(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "/home/andylu/.virtualenvs/scrapy_course/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 191, in crawl
    crawler = self.create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "/home/andylu/.virtualenvs/scrapy_course/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 224, in create_crawler
    return self._create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "/home/andylu/.virtualenvs/scrapy_course/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 229, in _create_crawler
    return Crawler(spidercls, self.settings)
  File "/home/andylu/.virtualenvs/scrapy_course/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 72, in __init__
    self.extensions = ExtensionManager.from_crawler(self)
  File "/home/andylu/.virtualenvs/scrapy_course/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 53, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "/home/andylu/.virtualenvs/scrapy_course/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 35, in from_settings
    mw = create_instance(mwcls, settings, crawler)
  File "/home/andylu/.virtualenvs/scrapy_course/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 167, in create_instance
    instance = objcls.from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/andylu/.virtualenvs/scrapy_course/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scrapy/extensions/feedexport.py", line 247, in from_crawler
    exporter = cls(crawler)
  File "/home/andylu/.virtualenvs/scrapy_course/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scrapy/extensions/feedexport.py", line 277, in __init__
    self.feeds[uri] = feed_complete_default_values_from_settings(feed_options, self.settings)
  File "/home/andylu/.virtualenvs/scrapy_course/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scrapy/utils/conf.py", line 118, in feed_complete_default_values_from_settings
    out = feed.copy()
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

How can I prevent the output file `Outputs/quotes_splash.json` to be appended to?
I'd prefer it to be overwritten completely every time anew.

---

**PS:**
Inspired by the help of Georgiy's answer below I found out, that the command-line help options would have revealed that indeed the output flag `-o` and `-O` makes all the difference. `scrapy crawl -h` yields:

```
(scrapy_course) andylu@andylu-Lubuntu-PC:~$ scrapy crawl -h
Usage
=====
  scrapy crawl [options] <spider>

Run a spider

Options
=======
--help, -h              show this help message and exit
-a NAME=VALUE           set spider argument (may be repeated)
--output=FILE, -o FILE  append scraped items to the end of FILE (use - for
                        stdout)
--overwrite-output=FILE, -O FILE
                        dump scraped items into FILE, overwriting any existing
                        file
--output-format=FORMAT, -t FORMAT
                        format to use for dumping items

Global Options
--------------
--logfile=FILE          log file. if omitted stderr will be used
--loglevel=LEVEL, -L LEVEL
                        log level (default: DEBUG)
--nolog                 disable logging completely
--profile=FILE          write python cProfile stats to FILE
--pidfile=FILE          write process ID to FILE
--set=NAME=VALUE, -s NAME=VALUE
                        set/override setting (may be repeated)
--pdb                   enable pdb on failure
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I inserted in the settings.py - file of my scrapy-project the
> following:

```py
    FEEDS = {"overwrite": True}
```

According to [docs(v.2.4)](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/2.4/topics/feed-exports.html) of usage `FEEDS` setting it should be like this: (it is not source of your error as It replaced by command line arguments (it has higher priority):

```py
FEEDS = {
    "quotes_splash.json": {
        "format": "json",
        "overwrite": True
         }
    }
```

To enable overwrite from command line You need to use `-O` (capital letter) argument 
instead of small `-o` (it is different).

```
  File "/home/andylu/.virtualenvs/scrapy_course/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scrapy/extensions/feedexport.py", line 277, in __init__
    self.feeds[uri] = feed_complete_default_values_from_settings(feed_options, self.settings)
  File "/home/andylu/.virtualenvs/scrapy_course/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scrapy/utils/conf.py", line 118, in feed_complete_default_values_from_settings
    out = feed.copy()
```

It looks like real source of Your error was during parsing filename feed uri `Outputs/quotes_splash.json` (it is not related to overwrite feature)

Command for overwrite for Scrapy command line tool needs to be like this:

```
scrapy crawl quotes_splash -O quotes_splash.json
```